# in swift 3, the bridge between [Double] and [NSObject] is gone?

Tags: swift, swift3

So in `Swift2.x`, below code works without issues:

define:

```
public class BarChartData
    public convenience init(xVals: [String?]?)
    {
        self.init(xVals: xVals, dataSets: [IChartDataSet]())
    }

    public convenience init(xVals: [NSObject]?)
    {
        self.init(xVals: xVals, dataSets: [IChartDataSet]())
    }
```

init:

```
let xs = Array(1..<10).map { return Double($0) }
let data = BarChartData(xVals: xs)
```

However in `Swift3`, `Xcode8` GM throws me error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'BarChartData' with an argument list of type '(xVals: [Double])'

If I change to

```
let data = BarChartData(xVals: xs.map { i in return i as NSObject })
```

Then it will work.

It seems in `Swift3`, the **bridge** between `[Double]` and `[NSObject]` is gone. Is there any documentation about this change or it's a bug?

Comment: See [SE-0072: Fully eliminate implicit bridging conversions from Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md). You could also write the conversion as `xs as [NSObject]`

Comment: Also documented in the beta 6 release notes: *"Bridging conversions are no longer implicit. The conversion from a Swift value type to its corresponding object can be forced with `as`."*

Comment: As @Hamish writes above, but to specify w.r.t. your comment _"It seems in Swift3, the bridge between `[Double]` and `[NSObject]` is gone"_: it's only the _implicit_ bridging that has been removed.

Comment: @Hamish thanks so much, please answer and I will accept it

Comment: Thanks guys! Solved